# Possible to use counter_cache with store_accessor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a [jsonb column](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json) (`data`) for which I define attributes with [store_accessor](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store/ClassMethods.html#method-i-store_accessor) like this:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  store_accessor :data, :comments_count
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
end
```

Is there any way to use Rails' `counter_cache`, saving the count in an attribute defined as per above?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that store_accessor is for [adding additional accessors to an existing store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html). If you are defining your store, you should use something like this :

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  store :data, :comments_count
  # store :data, accessors: [ :comments_count ], coder: JSON
end
```

You need to specify the counter_cache on the belongs_to size of the association.

Haven't tried this, but how about this?

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: :comments_count
end
```

EDIT:

Or

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: stored_attributes[:comments_count]
end
```

Comment: Your first suggestion gives the following error "NameError: undefined local variable or method `data' for #<Class:0x007f9708d46420>". And the second suggestion, the following error: "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer".

Comment: Btw, do you mean that using `store_accessor` isn't correct? Would I be better off with your `store` example?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: How do you want to access the comments_count? post.comments_count or post.data[:comments_count]?

Comment: It doesn't matter really, but with `store_accessor` I'm used to use the attribute directly, i.e. `post.comments_count`.

Comment: Could you give it a try?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what novelty the answer provides. If defining the store would be the obstacle or how to define `counter_cache` on the child association? Or it altogether. But not matter what, I'm sorry the provided solution doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It cannot find the attribute on the association. So I'm going with the established route to add an ordinary attribute :/